# How can I customize the URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website made by someone else and I have to make certain pages have URLs like `http://domain.com/title/` instead of `http://domain.com/foo/bar/title.php`. I couldn't find anything on the subject online and I couldn't understand anything from the question and answer I found on this website because I'm greener than the person who asked that question. I only know that the /foo/bar/ are supposed to be folders called 'foo' and 'bar', but there are no such folders in the files, where should I even start looking for manipulating the URL?

Comment: Try to use `.htaccess`

Comment: "I couldn't find anything on the subject online" This is a very common topic so it's impossible not to find something regarding this issue. sorry.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Either I don't know the exact term for this or google shows different results in my country. For me it just shows url shortening websites like bit.ly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add .htaccess file in you root foler and you can add lines like below:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^title  title.php?category=1 [PT]
RewriteRule ^foo  foo.php [PT]
```

For information : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Should I know any specific programming language before I can make sense of the examples?

Comment: How do I read the examples then? `^/([uge])/([^/]+)$` seems like just random symbols.

Comment: That part of the file is called a "pattern", which has it's own syntax, called "regular expression" or Regex for short. Regex is similar in most programing langauges. It's generally used to do search and or replace operations on strings.

Comment: If you're new to this kind of thing, this article looks like a good guide to get a basic understanding on URL rewriting and Regex https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ - I know the apache documentation can be a bit daunting at first.